# Program Automation in Windows using VB.NET 2008

Tags: vb.net, automation

I am trying to automate a program  using Visual BAsic.NET. The idea is to invoke my "Program" at the click of a button, pass inputs to the program and save the results it would generate.

For now I can invoke my program using VisualBasic.NET(comands: shell, appactivate), I can pass in data to the program( My.Computer.Keyboard.SendKeys("a")),( just that it is broken).

the main problem is that the data to be input goes  into a form with multiple tabs and I am not able to figure out the best way to select the correct tab so that I can throw my data in there and get to the results

Can some one please help me with this.

Also is this program has a dll( obviously  I am new to windows application programming), is there any way i can directly pass data to the dll and get results?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to look up reflection. A good starting point for me was

[vbdotnetheaven](http://www.vbdotnetheaven.com/UploadFile/rahul4_saxena/Reflection09122007031247AM/Reflection.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your time... 

no.. I dont understand that.. quite well..

how do i get to know more about this.. ( i mean reflection) what it does, how it does etC?